# Bootstrap 3 - Any support for "adaptative design" or conditionals?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website and the design comes with different responsiveness for desktop and small devices. In my case, I have a navbar. While for desktop works as a normal navbar, for small devices it has to be navbar-fixed-top.

My first solution came by repeating code and using the classes visible-xs and hidden-xs, but Im not particularly happy with repeating code. Is the any conditional statement that I can use to avoid this? Any other solution?

```
<!-- Desktop navbar -->
<nav class="hidden-xs navbar navbar-default navbar-menu" role="navigation" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        ....
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- Small devices -->
<nav class="visible-xs navbar-fixed-top navbar navbar-default navbar-menu" role="navigation" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        ....
    </div>
</nav>
```

Adding JS might be a solution but I would like to avoid refreshing the layout, so the user dont see from collapse to desktop version refresh. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this via CSS and a media query.

Just use the html with the `.navbar-fixed-top` class and put this CSS in your stylesheet.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        position: relative;
        top: auto;
    }        
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        max-height: none;
    }
}
```

Basically you are saying with this, that if the screen width is under 767px, the navbar should have `position: relative` and behave 'normal'. Above 767px screen-width, the navbar will be `position: fixed`, due to the class `.navbar-fixed-top` declarations.

The `body` need the `margin: 0`, since a fixed navbar uses a margin on the body element with the height of the fixed header, so that the content is not hidden behind it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually its in the other way around Im looking for, but this gives me a starting point.

Comment: ah ok, then you should be able to just switch `@media (max-width: 767px)` to `@media (min-width: 767px)`.